# ng-select uso del multiselect en Angular7

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo un formulario y para ello he usado el **ng-select** para así poder **hacer uso del multiselect**, el problema que me surge es que **al seleccionar varios elementos me crea un Array** y me da error al insertarlo en la db todos los datos.

Os dejo mi código y una captura del objeto relleno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<ng-select [multiple]="true" [closeOnSelect]="false" [hideSelected]="true" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Programa..." name="programa"  [(ngModel)]="fpaciente.programa" [disabled]="!active">
    <ng-option value='concertado'>Concertado</ng-option>
    <ng-option value='cdrr'>CDRR</ng-option>
    <ng-option value='pair'>PAIR</ng-option>
    <ng-option value='dispensacion'>Dispensación de medicación</ng-option>
    <ng-option value='comidas'>Almuerzo y/o Desayuno</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Aquí es donde inserto los registros en el campo programa de mi base de datos:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO pacientes VALUES (".
        "'{$data['historia']}'," .
        "'{$data['fecha_alta']}'," .
        "'{$data['dni']}'," .
        "'{$data['apellidos']}'," .
        "'{$data['nombre']}'," .
        "'{$data['direccion']}'," .
        "'{$data['poblacion']}'," .
        "'{$data['provincia']}'," .
        "{$data['cod_postal']}," .
        "'{$data['tlfn1']}'," .
        "'{$data['tlfn2']}'," .
        "'{$data['email']}'," .
        "'{$data['programa']}'," .
        "'{$data['fecha_nac']}'," .
        "'{$data['genero']}'," .
        "'{$data['estado_civil']}'," .
        "'{$data['profesion']}',".
        "'{$data['ssocial']}',".
        "'{$data['fibat']}',".
        "'{$data['tipo_paciente']}',".
        "'{$data['resumen']}',".
        "'{$data['terapeuta1']}'," .
        "'{$data['terapeuta2']}'," .
        "'{$data['terapeuta3']}'," .
        "'1'".
         ");";
```

Comment: Por lo que veo el problema no es de angular, entonces, sino de que tu BE no está sabiendo interpretar lo que le mandas

Comment: El error no viene de Angular, es con tu base de datos. Una solución que puedes hacer es transformar tu array a un objeto. Desde luego que no es lo más recomendable pero puede funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer un **join** algo asi como esto:

```
let tu_variable= this.programa.join();
```

luego debes hacer, cuando vas a seleccionar a editar, separar ese string por comas y llevarlos al ng_multiselect

Answer (score 0):

Intenta meter más lógica de programación en tu backend, está fatalmente vulnerable. Si es un proyector escolar, lee a cerca de buenas prácticas. Para solucionar rápido lo que preguntas, utiliza [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) Eso te ayudará a crear una cadena delimitada por comas a partir de un array.

```
"'{ implode(',', $data['programa'] ) }',"
```

Reitero, esta solución es trágica (Pero funcional), puesto que necesitas conocer más a cerca de SQL Injection